# Are 3-way interactions effects possible with visreg package?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm trying to use the `visreg` package for 3-way interactions. (I am able to fit 2-way interactions as shown below with my R reproducible code).

I am wondering if it is possible to plot 3-way interactions using `visreg`: "year" ; "age"; "education". Using `ggeffects` package, it is possible - but is it also possible with visreg?

(I previously already posted the same request on r-help a week ago, I did not get any answer, and on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/387416/visreg-r-package) (answer: "off-topic for this site")).

```
#install.packages("ISLR")
library(ISLR)
#install.packages("visreg")
library(visreg)
#install.packages("mgcv")
library(mgcv)

mod1 <- gam(wage ~ education+s(age,bs="ps") + year + te(age,year,bs="ps") +
            s(year,bs="ps",by=education,m=1) + te(year,age,by=education,bs=rep("ps",2)),
            data=Wage)

visreg(mod1, "year", by="education",partial=FALSE,overlay=TRUE)
```

Comment: I edited your question for clarity and to remove unnecessary bits. Possibly it shouldn't have been closed as offtopic on CV: I think you need to clarify whether this is a straight-up programming issue, or a modeling issue? Don't assume we have familiarity with visreg, give a link and spell out the issues for us. What goes wrong? What error message do you get? (please post it). Also, you need to make this use reproducible data (e.g. an example using any of the builtin R datasets should be fine).

Comment: Some people over on CV are very short-tempered whenever they perceive or assume something to be a programming issue. Also, reproducible code and data are strongly preferred.

Comment: If it works with ggeffects, why do you need visreg? Is there something that you can't achieve with ggeffects?